# How do I extract only the IPs from the data?

Tags: regex

Trying to pull some logs and break it down. The following regex match gives me a correct match for all 4 IPs: `([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}+)` but not sure how to either delete the rest of the data or "extract" the IPs. Only need the IPs as shown.

```
June 3rd 2020, 21:18:02.193 [2020-06-03T21:18:02.781503+00:00,192.168.5.134,0,172.16.139.61,514,rslog1,imtcp,]<183>Jun  3 21:18:02 005-1attt01 atas_ssl: 1591219073.296175 CAspjq31LV8F0b 146.233.244.131 38530 104.16.148.244 443 - - - www.yahoo.com F - - F - - - - - - -

June 3rd 2020, 21:18:02.193 [2020-06-03T21:18:02.781503+00:00,192.168.5.134,0,172.16.139.61,514,rslog1,imtcp,]<183>Jun  3 21:18:02 005-1attt01 atas_ssl: 1591219073.296175 CAspjq31LV8F0b 146.233.244.131 38530 104.16.148.244 443 - - - www.yahoo.com F - - F - - - - - - -
```

Need this:

```
192.168.5.134 172.16.139.61 146.233.244.131 104.16.148.244
192.168.5.134 172.16.139.61 146.233.244.131 104.16.148.244
```

Comment: Extract them all and join the matches with a space.

Comment: What language are you using? In PHP use `preg_match_all()` to get an array of matches. In Python use `re.findall()` to get a list of matches. Both languages then provide a way to join array/list elements with a space separator.

Comment: This is for Notepad++. Not quite sure how to "extract" them all.